# Pan through row of images

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a list of images and I want to align all of them side by side.

Since there are a lot of images and they overload the space of the screen width. So, I want to go navegate throught the images using the mouse. When I go to the right of the container of images, I navigate to the right and vice-versa.

How can I do something like this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is a Javascript image carousel. You can find [examples and reviews of some here](http://blarnee.com/wp/jquery-image-carousels-for-slidehow/).

Answer (score 0):

how about this one? http://kiusso.net/scripts/imageScroller_jquery_plugin/index.htm